# Como acceder a los objetos de un array json y mostrarlos

Tags: json, array

Hola comunidad estoy intentando  acceder a un array de objetos json pero aun no puedo alguien sabe como se puede acceder a un array a traves de un ciclo for.

mi cadena json es la siguiente:

```
var array = [{"id":1, "nombre":"Francisco"},{"id":2, "nombre":"Juan"}];
```

para tratar de acceder a ellos lo hago mediante un for asi

```
var resultado = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) { resultado = array[i]; }
```

Pero me itera uno por uno. ¿Alguien sabe como acceder a sus propiedades como id y nombre y mostrarlos en un div. Gracias espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: `resultado.id`  y `resultado.nombre` respectivamente

Comment: ¿Disculpa No se puede acceder a ellos por medio de indices? ya que los traigo de mi consulta de mi base de datos pero no quiero declararlos sino que sean dinámicos. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder a ellos es simple

```
// seria algo asi con tu ejemplo
resultado[posicion].id
resultado[posicion].nombre

// ya si los quieres mostrar en un elemento html lo podes hacer con vanilla js o jquery

// js puro ejemplo
var divHtml = document.createElement('div');

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
var spanHtml = document.createElement('span');
spanHtml.innerHTML = `Id = ${array[i].id} - Nombre = ${array[i].nombre}`;
divHtml.appendChild(spanHtml);
}

document.body.appendHtml(divHtml);
```